# Sublime Side Bar on the right side

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I start using Sublime Text 2. But having small issue, can't find the option to move the side bar (FOLDERS pan) to the right side of the window.

Can you please tell me how I can do it? Is there any plugin or setting option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly this feature is not supported.

See:

http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/54835-side-bar-on-the-right-side/

http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2340

Comment: It’s been a decade, and still, this feature is not supported.

Answer (score 5):

How about [SublimeFileBrowser](https://github.com/aziz/SublimeFileBrowser) ?

I haven't tried yet.

Comment: Looks like a good alternative. Haven't tried it yet either, though.